# showing fb publish dialog in graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using `FB.api("/[user_id]/feed")` method to publish to a friend's wall.
I know I need the publish_stream permission for this, and it works just fine. Problem is it auto-posts the stream on the friend's wall, no FB dialog whatsoever. That means, by Facebook terms of service, I have to design my own fb like window, and ask to approve the post before I actually post it. Is there a way of showing the FB dialog, when using the Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `FB.ui()` (see [example1](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui), [example2](http://fbrell.com/fb.ui/stream.publish))

Comment: Thanks serg, but I was looking for a way of doing it in the new API, rather than call old API using the new one. The reason is because lots of users, me included, have severe problems using the old API that way. stuck on a "Loading..." screen for the first time, for example. 

I was hoping there was a way of achieving this using the new API as well, and hope it works better..

Comment: @trueicecold That's an official way of doing it right now, there is no other way.